# Running android emulator on travis-ci without -no-window option

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci

I'd like to figure out if it will be possible to run the android emulator on travis-ci without -no-window option.

When I try [the example](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/#How-to-Create-and-Start-an-Emulator), and remove the `-no-window` option, then the `android-wait-for-emulator` part of the following code hangs:

```
# Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait
before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-19 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

I'm hoping there is some way to do this, because it appears that Firefox depends on it.

Perhaps a something like the [GUI & Headless browser testing](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/), but for the android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Without the `-no-window` attribute the system needs a Display.

Maybe you can try to add `export DISPLAY=:99.0` in `before_script`, as described in http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/ with the xvfb tool.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried numerous other system images and command line options, and this is the only thing that works for me so far.

```
- SYS_IMG="system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a"

- echo no | sdkmanager "$SYS_IMG"

- echo no | avdmanager create avd -n acib -k "$SYS_IMG" -f -c 100M -d 0

- emulator @acib -no-window &
```